# Rails search according to multiple checkbox value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I'm troubling to search according to multiple checkbox values like I have a `post` table where persons post by locations:

list of Checkboxes in form:

```
 #=> Form method get
<%= check_box_tag("post_location", "London") %>
<%= check_box_tag("post_location", "Azle") %>
<%= check_box_tag("post_location", "Azure") %>
<%= check_box_tag("post_location", "Arma") %>
```

Controller:

```
@posts= Post.where(["post_location LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:post_location]}%"]).where(["post_title LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:post_title]}%"])
```

But always show result based on the last checkbox.

How can show all results based on all checkbox values?

Thanks

Comment: make your textbox name as array first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know have you fixed this already or till now you troubling, Anyway, I'm writing an answer for future SO user help.

On the view file like below:

```
<%= check_box_tag("post_location[]", "London") %> London                                            
<%= check_box_tag("post_location[]", "Azle") %> Azle                                            
<%= check_box_tag("post_location[]", "Azure") %> Azure                                            
<%= check_box_tag("post_location[]", "Arma") %> Arma
```

If all checkboxes are checked then

```
"post_locations"=>["London","Azle","Azure","Arma"]
```

Now on the controller with pagination param like below:

```
if params[:search] #=> if you use inside search form
   @posts = Post.where('true').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
   @posts = @posts.where("post_title LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:search]}%") unless params[:search].blank?
   @posts = @posts.where(post_location: params[:post_location]) unless params[:post_location].blank?
else
  @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
end
```

On the `post_title` you can use anything like `post_title` or anything.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using same name of checkboxes, so the value of checkboxes gets overwritten, you need to get the `checkbox` value in array. So, you can use use `multiple: true` for it. Once the data comes in array, you can match it in your table

Comment: Are you able to get array of location in params?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add array with the name.
Here is the code for it

```
<%= check_box_tag "post_location[]", "London") %>
<%= check_box_tag "post_location[]", "Azle") %>
<%= check_box_tag "post_location[]", "Azure") %>
<%= check_box_tag "post_location[]", "Arma") %>
```

Comment: Just cross check in console parameters of post_location is array. you suppose to get array.  
refer this  
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NdBUyPF6yovCEYsjw/xcgacd/qxecAjeZjqrGGCrTp4bNT2C6bhw6R7mnMaefB1xOfcXzULsdc4zyXp8ebapBw==", "post"=>{"post_location"=>["London", "Azle", "Azure", "Arma"]}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= check_box_tag("post_location", "London") %>
<%= check_box_tag("post_location", "Azle") %>
<%= check_box_tag("post_location", "Azure") %>
<%= check_box_tag("post_location", "Arma") %>
```

The standard HTML for above helper is:

```
<input id="post_location" name="post_location" type="checkbox" value="London" />    
<input id="post_location" name="post_location" type="checkbox" value="Azle" />    
<input id="post_location" name="post_location" type="checkbox" value="Azure" />
<input id="post_location" name="post_location" type="checkbox" value="Azure" />
```

Here name is same so it will gives result of last checkbox.

You may take an arry for list of checkboxes as suggested by @Rankit Ranjan,

```
<%= check_box_tag "post_locations[]", "London") %>
<%= check_box_tag "post_locations[]", "Azle") %>
<%= check_box_tag "post_locations[]", "Azure") %>
<%= check_box_tag "post_locations[]", "Arma") %>
```

After this in your controller, you will receive it in parameter

```
 "post_locations"=>["London","Azle","Azure","Arma"]  ## I assume all checkboxes are selected.
```

Then in controller, query should look like:

```
@posts= Post.where(["post_location IN (?) ", "%#{params[:post_locations]}%"]).where(["post_title LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:post_title]}%"])
```